# Custom AutoFormat in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way to format using Regex but tie up a handful of replace-all expressions on the current document for formating? I regularly use a hand full of regex expressions to clean up my SQL scripts, and I would like to not have to do it by hand every time. Is there a way to hotkey all of these to run at once?

This is not relevant but here are the SQL Regex scripts that I use where -- is a comment and the second line is the replace variables. You can use this as a reference or use it for your own script if you like.

```sql
-- Add a space between = or + or * or / phrases
([@\w\d'")\]])([+=*\/]|<>|<=|>=|>|<)(['"@\w\d(-\[])
$1 $2 $3

-- Remove unnessisary space at the end of a line
([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/\d\w])\h+$
$1

-- Add space between minus sign. Doesn't work after a letter because it could be mistaken with a hyphan.
([\d)\]])([-])([\w\d(\[])
$1 $2 $3

-- Add a space after a , that comes after a letter, ), ', or "
([)\w\d'")])([,])([\w\d'"(@])
$1$2 $3

-- Fix dates in comments that are messed up from adding spacing to /
\* *(Created on: )?(\d{1,2}) *\/ *(\d{1,2}) *\/ *(\d)
* $1$2/$3/$4
```

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RegReplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Keith Hall pointed out, [packagecontrol.io/packages/RegReplace](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RegReplace), will do the job nicely.

But, FYI, if you wanted to create such a custom command directly it would go like this:

1. Pull down `Preferences > Browse Packages`... and then go into the User folder.
2. Create a file called `sql_cleanup.py` and paste in the following:

```
from sublime_plugin import TextCommand
import re

# Sublime automatically recognizes this class name as being the "sql_fixup" command
class SqlFixupCommand(TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self._edit = edit
        self._process_text()

    def _get_file_content(self):
        return self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))

    def _update_file(self, doc):
        self.view.replace(self._edit, sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()), doc)

    def _process_text(self):
        txt = self._get_file_content()

        # Add a space between = or + or * or / phrases
        txt = re.sub(r"([@\w\d'\")\]])([+=*\/]|<>|<=|>=|>|<)(['\"@\w\d(-\[])", r"\1 \2 \3", txt)

        # Remove unnecessary space at the end of a line
        txt = re.sub(r"([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\";'<>?,.\/\d\w])\h+$", r"\1", txt)

        # Add space between minus sign. Doesn't work after a letter because it could be mistaken with a hyphen.
        txt = re.sub(r"([\d)\]])([-])([\w\d(\[])", r"\1 \2 \3", txt)

        # Add a space after a , that comes after a letter, ), ', or "
        txt = re.sub(r"([)\w\d'\")])([,])([\w\d'\"(@])", r"\1\2 \3", txt)

        # Fix dates in comments that are messed up from adding spacing to /
        txt = re.sub(r"\* *(Created on: )?(\d{1,2}) *\/ *(\d{1,2}) *\/ *(\d)", r"* \1\2/\3/\4", txt)

        self._update_file(txt)
```

3. To optionally add your new command to the command palette, create a file called `sql_cleanup.sublime-commands` and paste in the following:

```
[
  { "caption": "SQL: Fix Up Code","command": "sql_fixup" },
]
```

4. To optionally add this command to Sublime's Tools menu (in a submenu called SQL), create a file called `Main.sublime-menu` with the following contents: (If there is already a submenu called SQL, then this will add it to whatever is already there.)

```
[
  {
    "id": "tools",
    "children": [
      {
        "caption": "SQL",
        "id": "sql-tools",
        "mnemonic": "S",
        "children": [
          {
            "caption": "Fix Up Code",
            "command": "sql_fixup" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

5. To optionally bind this command to a keystroke, create a file called `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` (or whatever platform you are on) with something like the following contents: (This example binds it to holding down the CTRL key and typing UQ.)

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+u", "ctrl+q"], "command": "sql_fixup" },
]
```